# Is there any way to specify YAML version when dumping config?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a config I want to store in a YAML file for future use. But I want to store `YAML 1.2` version as well.

```
import yaml
with open('r.yaml', 'w') as r:
    a = {'len' : 5, 'weidth' : 3}
    yaml.dump(a, r)
```

I want output as

```
%YAML 1.2
---
len: 5
weidth: 3
```

EDIT: Extension of above problem. 
Is it possible to remove redundancy when dumping multiple config in same file

```
import yaml
with open('r.yaml', 'w') as r:
    a = [{'len' : 5, 'weidth' : 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
    yaml.dump_all(a, r, version=(1,2))
```

And expected output

```
%YAML 1.2
---
len: 5
weidth: 3
---
a: 2
b: 4
```

Currently it is

```
%YAML 1.2
---
len: 5
weidth: 3
%YAML 1.2
---
a: 2
b: 4
```

Comment: If nothing else, you can simply write the version yourself. `r.write('%YAML 1.2\n---\n')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the version as a tuple of major and minor versions as a keyword argument to `yaml.dump`:

```
>>> yaml.dump({'foo': 'bar'}, sys.stdout, version=(1,2))
%YAML 1.2
---
foo: bar
```

The [documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) mentions the keyword attribute, but I didn't see a clear mention of *how* to pass the version. `version="1.2"` raises a `ValueError`, though the traceback made it clear how the value was intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you help me in the extension of problem posted in question.

Comment: That's a different question, not an extension of the original problem.

Comment: You are no longer dumping a single YAML document to the file, but multiple YAML files.